# Microcontroller wth integrated USB function + USB host controller

Tags: usb, microcontroller

I found this microcontroller AT83C5134/35/36 which has an inbuilt USB function, if i program this controller can i directly connect it to the modem ( an interface between the PC and telephone " the internet world ") for data transmission, or else i need something else ?? Please have a look at the data sheet of the same at http://www.alldatasheet.com/datasheet-pdf/pdf/181593/ATMEL/AT83C5134.html

and what exactly is a USB host controller ... i read some pages on the net but couldnt get the exact idea .. Can it be explained with an example ?

Comment: "connect it to the modem" -- which modem?

Answer (score 2):

There are USB hosts and USB devices. An example of a USB host is your PC; it connects to USB devices. The asymmetry in this communication is why the cables for USB have different connectors at each end.

If you want to build an embedded system that can talk to USB devices such as cameras, flash drives, etc., you need a USB host controller. If you want to build an embedded system that acts as a device, you need a USB device controller. If you want to do both, you need "USB On-The-Go" capability.

Answer (score 1):

AT83C5134/35/36 is not usb host controller. See device selection guide on Atmel's site - there are few microcontroller with usb host support. also You may be interested in ARM/MIPS/Blackfin - they sometimes also have usb host functionality